# Groups whose minimal number of generators is $\log_2(|G|)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, extremal-combinatorics

It's a classical exercise to show that a finite group $G$ has a minimal number of generators $\leq \log_2(|G|)$.

Clearly this bound is attained for $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^k$ ($k\geq 0$).

Moreover using the structure theorem for abelian groups, one can show that these are the only abelian groups for which this minimal number is exactly $\log_2(|G|)$.

Hence there are two natural questions:

> What happens for non-abelian groups ?
>
> And what happens if we loosen the constraint to $\lfloor \log_2(|G|)\rfloor$ in the abelian and non-abelian settings ?

If we stick  to $\log_2(|G|)$ it is clear that we're only dealing with $2$-groups. I don't know what more can be said...

I have even less ideas for the second question, because even for abelian groups it seems complicated, let alone nonabelian ones (For instance whenever $G$ is a $2$-group solution to the first question, I think $G\times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is a solution to the second one - EDIT : no this isn't true, as Derek Holt pointed out)

Ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal number of generators of a finite $p$-group $G$ is $k$, where $p^k$ is the order of the $G/\Phi(G)$, and $\Phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup of $G$. Since $\Phi(G)=1 \Leftrightarrow G \cong C_p^k$ for some $k$, it follows that the minimal number is exactly $\log_2 |G|$ if and only if $G \cong C_2^k$. That answers your first question.

I haven't thought about your second question, but I would guess that $C_2^k$ is still the only possibility with $\lfloor \log_2|G|\rfloor$ generators. Your other example does not work because $C_2^k \times C_3 \cong C_2^{k-1} \times C_6$ is $k$-generated.

There is one exception to my guess: the nonabelian group $D_6 \cong S_3$ of order $6$ needs $2$ generators. But I am conjecturing that any other group of order $2^k\times 3$ is $k$-generated.

Comment: Thank you for your correction about my "example" ! Also thank you for your remark about the Frattini subgroup!

Comment: I'll wait to see if anyone has ideas about the second part before accepting your answer

Comment: Here is a sketch of a proof for the last question. First, we can assume that the Sylow $2$-subgroup is elementary abelian. 


If it is normal, then we have a group of the form $2^k:3$. Now take an irreducible module for the Sylow $3$-subgroup. It has dimension one or two, and you get either a $C_6$ or an $A_4$. Either way, you can generate it with one fewer element than the number of prime divisors of the order.

Comment: If the Sylow $2$-subgroup is not normal, then the group looks like $E.S_3$. You can consider the index two subgroup $E:3$ and repeat the argument above, assuming $E$ is not trivial. (If $E=1$, then we recover $S_3$ as the unique example.)

Comment: Yes that sounds right!